# how to close window using javascript that is not opend by script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tab that I want to close  after 5 seconds, so I used:

```
window.close()
```

but it is not working neither on firefox nor on chrome, so after googling I used:

```
window.open('','_parent',''); 
window.close();
```

still not working, also I tried:

```
open(location, '_self').close();
```

not working, and I tried to completely redirect the page to another using:

```
window.open('/close','_parent','');
```

then in the close page I have:

```
<script>
window.close();
</script>
```

still did not work, how may I close the tabe using javascript?

Comment: What did you do to make it happen after 5 seconds? Maybe show us the rest of your code - will make it a lot easier to help you

Comment: @MosheSommers that what the clients want, that after 5 seconds for the web page to close.
I am not posting all code to keep it focused on the issue if you need something specific I will post it.

Comment: `window.close()` Usually works, there's probably something else in your code breaking it.